# How do I start building a map worthy of a society?

Tags: map-making

How do I take a fantasy society with their own variations (architecture, fields, etc,) and the basic landforms I want to see, and integrate it into a map with determinable borders, cities, for better roleplaying?

Comment: Welcome, Bajortski. Your question is a bit difficult to answer: it's unclear if you're asking how to make a map, how to make a specific kind of map, or how to represent these things on a map; the best way to do those things depend on the purpose of the map, and may also a matter of opinion. Can you add more specific detail to help focus the question?

Comment: Sure, my apologies, I’ll fix it

Comment: Welcome to the site, Bajortski. Please note that we strongly encourage users to [wait at least 24 hours](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023/6986) before accepting an answer. StackExchange has users all over the world and accepting early may discourage others from offering better answers than what you have already received. Also, don't forget to upvote answers that are helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer for how to deal with the effects of particular cultural norms; that sounds like something too intricate for an existing tool. For just creating maps, though, have you looked at [Azgaar's Fantasy Map Generator](https://azgaar.github.io/Fantasy-Map-Generator/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to start is considering which climate and terrain would be more appropriate, this way you can have a rough idea of the latitude and geological features. Political borders usually respect geographic borders to some extent. When it comes to international borders, things can get more arbitrary, especially if they derive of central plan rather than a territorial dispute between city-states.

As for where to put cities, as long as it has a source of water, food and has easy access to trade, you can put it where you please, but don't put them to close together. A great city in a mountain is a big no no, but you can make it work with magic or plot reasons (a mad king pointed there and said "Make me a castle").